# MySQL SELECT queries of same limits getting slower and slower

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm using PHP & MySQL for my website and have to aggregate some metrics to generate a report for the client. The metrics can be found in a 4-million row table, which uses the MyISAM engine and is distributed in 12 PARTITIONS.

In a PHP loop (a for-loop), for each iteration, I retrieve 1000 rows that match specific ids with

```
id = X OR id =Y OR id = Z
```

(I'm not using any inner join with a temporary table like UNION 1 id UNION 2 etc. as it is a little bit slower, might be because of the partition option that relies on the hash of the id).

The problem is that the queries are getting slower and slower. It might be caused by something that is cached progressively, but I don't know what.

Any help would be very precious, many thanks.

Comment: Is the number of rows in your large table growing over time? Is there an index on this `id` column you're searching multiple times? (`OR` clauses can cause multiple searches.) Is the `id` a primary or unique key?

Comment: Aggregation of matrix... if there are still joins involved with additional tables, is there something else we are not seeing.  Can you post the query causing the problem/delay.

Comment: The id is a primary key and there's no join. As a simpler solution and for long-term purposes, I'm using Hadoop now! Problem solved! Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL gets very slow when you use a LIMIT that starts deep in the index. Check out this article for optimizing late row lookups:

http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

Comment: Anyway you can update your answer with a relevant excerpt from that link in case the link goes dead?

Comment: Just checked it, yeah I think it was the problem, thanks! I've developped another solution, mystery solved!